# How to fix ClassCastException when using localized n-m relations with Smartedit?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

In Hybris 6.7.0, using I have a component that contains a localized list of another component.

I have been able to implement this using a n-m localized relationtype to implement a localized list that contains the component.

It works perfectly in CMS cockpit. However, in smartedit, it causes a ClassCastException.

The default converter seems to fail to recognize the collection type and therefore trying to cast the collection to a item model which causes the error.

Is there anyway to implement a localized collection that won't causes the exception in SmartEdit?

I have tried using a map and collection pair for the localization instead of a localized relation but the same problem occurred.

2019-3-7 - Updates: After a series of trial and error, I have realized that the LocalizedCollection will never be called because all localized attribute in Hybris is stored with an item type of MapType, which does not trigger the localizedCollection getter as it check if the localized attributs is of type CollectionType.

It seems to be a bug on SAP side. I am currently trying to come up with a temporary fix for the problem.